# Function only diplays properties once

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have a function that for some reason, just seems to only display `$Properties` once, no matter how many users are passed to the script. Tried to throw in just the `$user` passed into the script to display but, that too only displays once. Not too sure why it's doing this as I have exhausted ideas on what it may be:

```
Function Set-DRAUserProperty {
    Param (
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]$UserName,

        $Company,
        $Department,
        $Name,
        $O, 
        $PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName,
        $TelephoneNumber,
        $Title
    )
    DynamicParam
    {
        if ($UserName.Split(',').Count -le 1) {
            $displayNameAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $displayNameAttribute.Mandatory = $false
            $attributeCollection = new-object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $attributeCollection.Add($displayNameAttribute)
            $displayNameParam = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter('DisplayName', [string], $attributeCollection)
            $paramDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
            $paramDictionary.Add('DisplayName', $displayNameParam)
            $paramDictionary
       }
    }
    Begin 
    {
        $OrgBoxOu   = "*OU=xxxxxxxxx"
        $Parameters = $PSBoundParameters
        $Properties = @{}
    }
    Process 
    {
        foreach ($User in $UserName) 
        {   
            try {
                $SelectedUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties DisplayName
                    if ($SelectedUser) {
                        $Parameters.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Key -ne 'UserName'} | 
                            ForEach-Object -Process `
                            {
                                if ($_.Key -eq 'DisplayName' -and $SelectedUser.DistinguishedName -like $OrgBoxOu) {
                                    if ('FirstNamePreferred' -in $Properties.Keys) {
                                        Continue
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $Properties.Add($_.Key, $_.Value)
                                        $Properties.Add('FirstNamePreferred', $_.Value) 
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    if ($_.Key -in $Properties.Keys) { 
                                        Continue
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $Properties.Add($_.Key, $_.Value) 
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        $Properties.GetEnumerator()
                        #Set-DRAUser -Identifier $SelectedUser.DistinguishedName -Properties $Properties @DRA_Server_Splat -ErrorAction Stop
                    }

                    else {
                        Write-Host -Object "No valid member selected!"
                    }
            }
            catch {
                Write-Host -Object "ERROR: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
                continue
            }

        }

    }
    End { }
}
```

When running the function,

- `Set-DRAUserProperty -UserName Abe,Abe -Company ssc`

. . . the output is only displayed once:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Company                        ssc
```

What i'm tring to achieve is having the values be splatted onto another cmdlet, but it won't work as long as my `$Properties` hashtable only displays once. So expected output would be it display the hashtable for each user that's been passed to the function:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Company                        ssc  

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Company                        ssc
```

Just looking for some fresh eyes that can point me in the right direction and/or, shed some light on what might be happening (*wrong*). *Not sure what could be causing the issue so can't pin-point it to a specific code section*.

Please edumecate me:)

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, ahhhh my fault! Just updated the post. Should just display the hashtable foreach user that is passed to the function. Thank ya!

Comment: At first glance, `$Properties = @{}` should be defined inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: If you are passing in the same user twice, it looks like your code is set to not return any output if the key already exists in the $properties hash table? Have you tested this with two different users? Because your example you are using the same user twice.

Comment: Moving `$Properties = @{}` below the `foreach ($User in $UserName){` loop gives me the expected output.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, that was it :'). Man, I was so stumped. Post the answer so you can get the credit! @ Chad, different users gave me the same result, Santi's suggestion worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to define the `hashtable` inside the `foreach` loop instead of inside the `begin { ... }` block:

```
foreach ($User in $UserName) 
{
    $Properties = @{}
    ....
    ....
}
```

But if you want to understand **why it was not working before?**, this is your hint:

```
if ($_.Key -in $Properties.Keys) { 
    '{0} is in $Properties.Keys :)' -f $_.Key
    Continue
}
```

Which yields:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Company                        ssc
Company is in $Properties.Keys :)
Company is in $Properties.Keys :)
```

And this only happens because `$Properties` is the same on each iteration (because it was defined in the `begin { ... }` block).

Comment: May you always find the pair to your sock anytime, and everytime! Thanks;)

Comment: @AbrahamZinala you're always cracking me up with these comments man lol. Always a pleasure to help you.